# recieving error in linearLayout

Tags: android

I seem to be getting an error in my `linearLayout` saying `android:Layout_width` and height are missing.Here is my code below if anyone can help.Id appreciate it

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: This code has no error. show whole code or try to rebuild your project again.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace 2nd line of your layout. You mentioned `xmlns:android` for tools also. Please replace your layout as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: If it resolved your issue then please mark as accepted answer. You can see green right symbol below votes.So it will help others also.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingLeft="16dp"
   android:paddingRight="16dp"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:gravity="center">

 </LinearLayout>
```

Try that if not work then clean your project and rebuilt